# How can I suppress transient HIGH signals in an opto-isolated digital circuit with pullup resistor

Tags: opto-isolator, pullup

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6l84U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am recording an opto-isolated signal using the opto-isolated output described here: http://softwareservices.flir.com/BFS-U3-04S2/latest/Family/ElectricalGPIO.htm . It is a camera strobe, and is supposed to be held LOW when the camera is not exposing. While that is mostly true, when it is being held low, it regularly (~200 pulses/s), transiently (<40us pulse) deflects HIGH.

How can I suppress this noise? My interpretation is that the pullup is "overcoming" the optocoupler, but I can't figure out how to balance them. Should I increase the pullup resistance? Or would it be better to add a capacitor?

Update: Thanks for the feedback, I attached a schematic and fixed the link. The transient HIGH is definitely not part of how it's supposed to work, the actual shutter open signal is there, and has clear 3000us pulses. The short deflections appear randomly and are actually probably shorter than 40us, they're one sample at 30kS/s.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Your link doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question and use the site's built-in schematic editor to draw the circuit so that we're not trying to rely on external links.

Comment: Hey, that link gives me a 404 error. Also, I wouldn't describe a 40ms pulse as a transient or as noise. The way you describe it it seems just part of the way that camera strobe works. Are you saying that the opto-coupler pulses at 200hz with 40ms pulse width, and you want to keep your resulting signal low continuous during this period? Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @Thijs: The question is flip-flopping between milliseconds and microseconds.  The correct units are certainly microseconds, as you couldn't have 200 pulses in a second of duration greater than 5ms.

Comment: It's not quite clear where the noise is: in the output of your circuit, or also in your input signal?

Comment: The noise is in the output, and I'm assuming it's arising due to the circuit I made, or at least that I could suppress it by changing the circuit.

Comment: @Ewave it sounds to me like changing the pull up to eg. 10K would be an easy experiment? If that's still not working, I'd suggest showing traces of both the input and the output here. Are you using a scope? Or just reading a digital input? An analog input? It's not very clear :)